# Best way to store bunch of constant values in .NET

Tags: c#, c++, xml, header, storage

This is basically a a design question:

I am rewriting an application in C# which is basically written in C++. C++ has this nice concept of Header files which will gold a lot of declared constant values for the consuming file.

However, we do not have Header files in C#. I may have two options

1. Create a class which will hold a lot of constant values for me(No so standard)
2. Store values in XML (Standard-But involves a lot of parsing hassle)

Which is a better solution? Is there any other solution that I may not know of?

Comment: I don't see what's "not so standard" about using `const` values in C# - that's about as close to the C++ version as you can get. And XML parsing isn't "a lot of hassle" with LINQ to XML... it's really very simple. Are these *really* constants, or are they likely to change over time? If they're genuine constants, I can't see how XML is helpful.

Comment: Since they are all in .H file in c++. More likely that they are all Genuinely constants.

Comment: Not to mention that if your code so fond of constants everywhere you probably need to rethink your design. Unless you're dealing with scientific data or the like.

Comment: What kind of values are you specifically talking about?

Comment: @Californicated: Right, so what's your objection to using `const` in C#? That seems like an obvious parallel... admittedly if you can place them in appropriate classes (associated with the value) that would be even better.

Comment: I do not have any objection against using consts and I think they hold a great value. However, not to object but I was not sure if it is a good design to define a class with the purpose of holding bunch of values. It would be treating a class as  a data storage. But there is 35 constants in total. So I think it would not be that bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally i'd use a `static` class and place all the values in there.

```
public static class Constants
{
   public const int Ten = 10;
   public const int Twenty = 20;
   ....
}
```

*EDIT*

*As @JonSkeet suggested, it's better if you store these values in classes they pertain to, however, that might not always be possible.*

Comment: OK. I wasn't so sure if using a class for the purpose of holding values is a good idea. Just needed a confirmation :)

Comment: @Californicated: Well don't use a specific class unless you have to - if they naturally fit in other classes, that's *better*... but sometimes it doesn't work out that way.

Comment: On the slight chance that what you are storing are all strings, then consider a .resx file. These are designed to hold string 'constants' but offer more flexibility, such as the ability to switch to other languages or cultures.